# How to create tab's activitys before click on TabWidget bar?

Tags: android, android-activity, tabs

i need to get the Activitys initialize , before anyone click on them . That is cause i have a video in one of them , and i need to have that Activity created to play the video from another tab (or activitys) .

I have this code to initialize the tab content but not the activitys into them :

```
//Init Tabs
Resources res = this.getResources(); 
TabHost tabHost = getTabHost(); 

tabHost.getTabWidget().setDividerDrawable(R.drawable.tab_divider);

setupTab(tabHost,MyInitActivity.class,res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_icon),res.getString(R.string.tab_init));
setupTab(tabHost,MusicGroupActivity.class,res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_icon),res.getString(R.string.tab_playList));
setupTab(tabHost,SearchActivity.class,res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_icon),res.getString(R.string.tab_search));
setupTab(tabHost,VideoActivity.class,res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_icon),res.getString(R.string.tab_video));
```

I have seen code like this to try it :

```
tabHost.setCurrentTab(number);
```

but that seems to not run when you change immediately cause when i do

Context context = getTabHost().getChildAt(3).getContext();

it throws to me a null exception.

Anyone knows how to do this?

**ADDED**

```
private void setupTab( TabHost mTabHost,Class<? extends Activity> activityclass,Drawable image, String tag) 
{

    View tabview = createTabView(mTabHost.getContext(),image,tag);
    TabSpec setContent = mTabHost.newTabSpec(tag).setIndicator(tabview).setContent(new Intent(this, activityclass));
    mTabHost.addTab(setContent);
}
```

Thanks for all

Comment: What exactly method setupTab do? Does it call .setContent(new Intent(this, SearchActivity.class)), something like this? tabHost.setCurrentTab(number) works perfectly for me

Comment: But when i try to ( getTabHost().getChildAt(3).getContext() ) , it throws me a null like a HOUSE .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do the following in the `onCreate()` (say i have 4 tabs)

```
tabHost.setCurrentTab(0); 
tabHost.setCurrentTab(1); 
tabHost.setCurrentTab(2); 
tabHost.setCurrentTab(3); 

tabHost.setCurrentTab(Tab_I_Want);
```